# Show the next number is not rational

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, analytic-number-theory

I dont have any idea to prove this number is not rational

$\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7 ^{2}}+\frac{1}{7 ^{6}}+...+\frac{1}{7 ^{n!}}+...$

Please help.

Comment: Does $[x]$ refer to the nearest integer function, or are they just parentheses?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{7(2)}+\frac{1}{7(6)}+...+\frac{1}{7(n!)}+...$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{7(k!)}$$

$$=\frac{1}{7}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}=\frac{e-1}{7}$$

Comment: Unfortunately $e = 1 + \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$ is irrational.

Comment: @YiyuanLee Thanks so much for the remainder.

Comment: And therefore the original expression is irrational.

Comment: Oh sorry, i was wrong to write the problem. I will fix it.